# Squid / IPtables allow only connections when accessing a certain proxy domain

Tags: iptables, squid, access-control-list

I'm not sure if this is a Squid subject or IPTables.

In my Squid configuration I have something like this setup:

```
http_port proxy.example.com:8080
```

I would like Squid to only accept connections from users connecting using 'proxy.example.com' as the proxy domain.

In other words if someone were to connect using another a domain that points the my server on port 8080 I want them to be denied access to proxy, including accessing the IP address directly.

Is this doable in Squid? If not how would I set this up in IPtables?

Answer (score 1):

You're definently taking this the wrong way.

What you're trying to be is most likely complicated and will definently add no extra security whatsoever. You should consider filtering the IPs of the people trying to connect to the proxy instead.

Although it's bad idea, I think this is not possible in Squid.

Comment: Perhaps this is too complicated, but I had thought of filtering IPs and it won't work for me. When I'm trying to connect to the proxy from home it will be from a dynamic IP.

The security is weak because it relies on a secret - ie. the domain and subdomain must be known, but at this point it provides enough security for my needs. If there isn't a way to do this I'll setup a username and password.

Comment: I think this will not be possible.

Comment: I had hoped there was some squid configuration setting I was overlooking or not understanding.